# Take the Date value in angular to add new user

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a db with some users, I have to add a new user to this list but I have a problem with the Date value. I take the fiel "nome(name)" and "cognome(surname)" with nome.value because they're a string but I have a problem with the anno_n(birth) because it's a Date type

```js
COMPONENT.HTML

  <div class="lista pt-5">
    <h2 class="text-dark">Aggiungi un nuovo partecipante</h2>
    <form class="row row-cols-lg-auto g-3 align-items-center float-center" (ngSubmit)="add(nome.value, cognome.value, anno_n.value)" (ngSubmit)="loadUser()" style="justify-content: center;">
      <div class="col-12">
        <label class="visually-hidden" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername">Nome</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername" required #nome placeholder="Nome">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <label class="visually-hidden" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername">Cognome</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername" required #cognome placeholder="Cognome">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <label class="visually-hidden" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername">Data di nascita</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername" required ng-model="anno_n.value" #anno_n useValueAsDate placeholder="Data di nascita (GG/MM/AAAA)">
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="col-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow-lg">Salva</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

```css
COMPONENT.TS

add(nome: string, cognome: string, anno_n: string): void {
      this.PartecipantiService.addP(nome, cognome, anno_n).subscribe(res => {
          console.log(res);
          this.loadUser();
        })
      }
```

```html
export interface Partecipanti {
    id: number;
    nome: string;
    cognome: string;
    anno_n: Date;
  }


SERVICE.TS
addP(nome: string, cognome: string, anno_n: string): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.post<Partecipanti>(this.partecipantiUrl, {
       nome: nome,
       cognome: cognome,
       anno_n: new Date(anno_n)
     }, this.httpOptions).pipe(
       tap((newPartecipante: Partecipanti) => this.log(`partecipante aggiunto w/ id=${newPartecipante.id}`)),
       catchError(this.handleError<Partecipanti>('addP'))
     );
   }
```

Comment: Hello hello, couple of quetsions,: 1.: What is your problem? You just state that you have one. 2.: The information where and how `nome`. `cognome`, and `anno_n` are defined is missing.

Comment: When I add a new user Date does’t work

Comment: Okay, what is not working? Is there any error message? What happened vs. what did you expect to happen?

Comment: The function show only My new name and surname, but My date field is empty. But if I change the input date into input text it work

Comment: Could you please provide the definition of `nome`, `cognome`, and `anno_n`. They should be inside the controller (inside "`component.ts`").

Comment: export class PartecipantiComponent implements OnInit {
  partecipanti: Partecipanti[] = new Array();
  constructor(public http: HttpClient,
    public PartecipantiService: PartecipanteService
    ) { }

Comment: I want to know where the values are defined that are passed into `add`, so this snippet: `(ngSubmit)="add(nome.value, cognome.value, anno_n.value)"`. Also, please edit your question instead of posting a comment :)

Comment: Ah, what exactly is the following log printing: `tap((newPartecipante: Partecipanti) => this.log(\`partecipante aggiunto w/ id=${newPartecipante.id}\`))`?

Comment: this is for my messages service

Answer (score 0):

You're using an input of type "date" - this already returns a Date, and you are again converting it to date in your service. Remove the `anno_n: new Date(anno_n)` from your POST call and see if this works.

Comment: I added 'anno_n: new Date(anno_n)' after,if I simply add 'anno_n:anno_n' it doesn't work

Comment: If I write anno_n:anno_n, the error is POST http://localhost:8080/partecipante 400

Comment: Looks like the issue is your backend cannot understand/parse the date. Convert the date to a string first depending on what your backend is expecting: ISO or Local. I had a similar issue before, and I converted to string "YYYY/MM/DD" and it worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `console.log` in your service

```js
addP(nome: string, cognome: string, anno_n: string): Observable<any> {
     console.log(new Date(anno_n))
     ...
   }
```

If it prints the correct date, then your problem is with the api, it probably doesn't accept a date object. Why bother converting it anyways? Just keep it as a string and convert it when you need it.

```js
export interface Partecipanti {
    id: number;
    nome: string;
    cognome: string;
    anno_n: string;
  }

addP(nome: string, cognome: string, anno_n: string): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.post<Partecipanti>(this.partecipantiUrl, {
       nome: nome,
       cognome: cognome,
       anno_n: anno_n
     }, this.httpOptions).pipe(
       tap((newPartecipante: Partecipanti) => this.log(`partecipante aggiunto w/ id=${newPartecipante.id}`)),
       catchError(this.handleError<Partecipanti>('addP'))
     );
   }
```

**Edit**

So your api probably wants a `string` a `number` or a `Date` object.

To convert from `Date` to `string` (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ)

```js
myDateString = myDateObject.toISOString()
```

To convert from `Date` to `number` (unix milliseconds)

```js
unixMillis = myDateObject.getTime()
```

The `Date constructor` accepts both these values to convert them back into a date object.

```js
myDateObject = new Date(myDateString)
```

OR

```js
myDateObject = new Date(unixMillis)
```

You need to figure out what your api actually wants, and make sure `anno_n` is in the correct format when you send it.

Comment: And how I can take as a string and convert when I need?

Comment: My console show the date but in the long format (with second etc.) and show a POST ERROR 400

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to convert, you need to find out what your api actually wants, and need to make sure the information you're sending is in the correct format.